# Finder badge icon not refresh after complete sync in Finder Extension in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode7, findersync

I am new to MAC development and using finder sync extension and successfully set badge icons for file and folder but my issue is that when i complete sync any file or folder to server the badge icon is not changing form sync to complete state. Please any suggestion how do i can refresh my file/folder badge icon  (Like Dropbox)

Comment: You can apply new image to the file when you get notification that file is in sync with server . Your extension is responsible for updating the images based on the state.

Comment: extension update the images after change focus of root directory but don't change the images when we are on same directory and try to upload some file on that directory

Comment: Have you got any solution? Because i am facing same issue.

Comment: @jigs Still googling to find the solutions Have you find any solutions for this please let me know Thanks

Comment: any progress here?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, First establish an Inter Process communication between your app and your extension. In an IPC, your app acts as a client and extension act as a server.
Now you know the state of a specific file, so just send the file path and status to the extension through IPC, Once extension receives the path and status, then call the Finder Sync controller’s **setBadgeIdentifier:forURL:** method to set the appropriate badge.

Comment: Even though I have an IPC between FinderSync and the MainApp, I'm still facing the issue where Finder doesn't show sync icon in Finder column view. Copy-file circle-progress animation seems to affect it. Just blank white space is shown, regardless of how many times I call the `setBadgeIdentifier` method.